# Is it correct for Java system properties to be used to set and get arbitrary program parameters?

Tags: java

It is possible using `-Dproperty=value` arguments to set arbitrary system properties (not some fixed set of system properties actually used by the JVM) and a program can get these properties later using `System.getProperty("property")`.  Is it correct to do this?

I haven't found an authoritative answer on this, so that's why I'm asking here.  It seems to me that program parameters should be set through command line arguments to the program, not to the JVM.  However, perhaps this is an accepted practice that just isn't documented anywhere I've looked so far.  I'd like to be sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think Java system properties are used to pass values from command line to libraries or plugins *inside* the execution. It is, that insider component has no direct way to receive the parameter from the main program that's executing it. So it reads it from a "context" that Java system properties are.

If we look at it as layers, command line arguments would be parameters for the inmediate lower layer, and system java properties are context for all the lower layers.

```
command line: arguments + properties
   main program: uses arguments
      some library/plugin: uses properties from context
```

If it's not this way the main program should have to carry all the parameters that user could set to the lower layers and it can be very cumbersome.

I don't like to depend on contextual properties so if I design a program I'd try to pass over all the properties in some non-global way. But it can be very handy some times (and using namespacing it's not probable they collide).

Comment: I agree with this line of reasoning.  However, just to really put the last nail in this thing, is there any documentation anywhere that says that this use is acceptable or that it is known and will continue to be supported by the JVM?

Comment: No idea. It should be nice to have some guide on how to do it well :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is not "incorrect" and there are programs and libraries that do use their own system properties for configuration.

However, it is probably more practical to put configuration parameters for your software in a configuration file (in whatever format you think is suitable - a `.properties` file, an XML file, or something else). It is cumbersome, especially if you have many configuration parameters, to have to put all those parameters on the command line with `-Dname=value` options.

Comment: Agreed, but these could also be used to specify one or two or a handful of properties files (as they are being used in this case).  Shouldn't these just be command line arguments?  I can see that using system properties this way is useful and flexible, I am just interested to hear if there is any justification for this or if it's some sort of specified acceptable usage, or if it just happened to work and became a pattern.

Comment: Is there any documentation on whether this is an acceptable or supported use?

Comment: It is supported; the Java API documentation doesn't warn you against using this. Why do you need an "authoritative" answer and who's authority is good enough for you to trust?

Comment: Authoritative would be from The Maker, as in Oracle.  See my answer.  I guess "not warning against this" isn't usually good enough justification for me.  Some other programming languages (C++) have compilers that have undefined behavior when you wade into gray areas that are not clearly specified.

Comment: @Doug, the `System.getProperty()` methods are part of the standard API. They will not disappear; the API docs are the authoritative docs from Oracle. Also the [docs for the Java launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) from Oracle say that you can set system properties with `-Dname=value`. That will also not change very soon, otherwise lots of software that uses this wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: I guess the question is whether setting "system properties" also means application properties.  (Clearly it does, it just wasn't obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to set some of your application settings. I think of settings as a contrast to program arguments. For example. Let's think abount some file converter. It converts file A to B. So files A and B should be command line params. If you converter needs some temporary folder you can make id settable by `-Dmy.package.tempfolder=\my\tmp\folder`. But there should be a default setting for that and the program should work without this setting.

Think  about it as an alternative to .properties file. .properties file will be more convinient of course.

Comment: Why not set the folder using a third command line parameter rather than using a system property?

Comment: I'm interested to know why these are considered "program settings" when they're actually JVM system properties.  Theoretically they could clash with future JVM system properties, or a JVM could ignore ones that aren't used, and this would just be undefined behavior for an unintended use.

Comment: Think about it as a setting like max JVM memory heap, logging level etc. This doesn't change logic of your program, just changes the environment. Of course you can add third command line parameter, but why should you complicate your programs 'API' if only 2% of users would use that?

Comment: It's good to use your package name in order not to collide with other system properties. Some libraries (e.g. java.util.logging) uses system settings to pass some config parameters. For example you can change logging behaviour with `java.util.logging.config.file` setting or you can change Swing theme with some system props too. You can do this in any Java app that uses JUL or Swing, but you shouldn't process all of them as your command-line params. Can you see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to know what you're doing. If your application is a standalone application, system properties provide an easy to use way to pass named arguments, in any order, to the program, and I don't see anything intrinsically bad in using them.

If your app is a webapp that must be deployed in a app server shared by multiple webapps, then it might not be a good idea, especially if you aren't allowed to change how the server is started, or if you have to deploy multiple versions of the same application.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html:

> For example, the following invocation of getProperty looks up the
>   System property called subliminal.message. This is not a valid system
>   property, so instead of returning null, this method returns the
>   default value provided as a second argument: "Buy StayPuft
>   Marshmallows!"
>
> `System.getProperty("subliminal.message",
>                      "Buy StayPuft Marshmallows!");`

This implies that properties other than those used by the JVM are "invalid".  However, later in the same document, it gives the example of loading a properties file containing the same property setting.

> subliminal.message=Buy StayPuft Marshmallows!

It only advises "In general, be careful not to overwrite system properties."

So it seems that this is a supported use of System Properties.  It looks like a case of misleading naming.  When I hear "System Properties" I think "properties of the JVM" where the JVM is the system.  While the properties are used for this, they can also be used for application settings.  I think I'll make a mental note to think of this as "System and Application Properties".

Does anyone disagree with this?